# Leveling a floor by sistering- Hanging question

Tags: joists, hanging

I'm looking to take on a project of leveling my floors. It's a pier and beam foundation. At the recommendation of my co-worker, my trade schools carpentry instructor, I think sistering is the way to go.

My question comes in on how/if the sisters need to be hung or resting on something. To completely level the floor after some foundation leveling is done, I'm very sure I'll run into the sisters butting up against the bottom plates of my walls. At this point, I wouldn't be able to hang the sisters and they would only be attached to the original joists. As long as the original joists are in sound condition, will they be able to take the additional weight of the sisters? Would this be structurally sound (in general, I'm sure that could be a very lengthy answer with specifics)?

I understand I'm giving vague details. I'm not at all about to start the project, so I'm seeking out as much information as possible. I appreciate any guidance!

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding: You're suggesting taking up foor and subfloor, sistering the floor joists with levelled pieces to get a level surface,  then putting down subfloor and floor again?  My solution so far has just been to add bases to furniture in the bad corner that give them a level footing, and accept that people walking through that corner may notice the tilt. In a house that's over 100 years old, nothing is either level, plumb, or square..

Comment: What is the maximum the current floor is out of level?  Are we talking 2+"?  Taking off the whole subfloor and sistering is quite an intensive job.  What is your end goal, 1/8" over 10'?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In general sisters don't need additional support other than being attached to the existing joists.

beams are usuallty sufficiently over-engineered that the extra dead load of the sisters doesn't have significant impact.

Joists are most rigid the ends so there's no need to enhance the hangers.